# Story Identification: Evil Vicar seeking power of universe

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am trying to identify a story I read around 2006-ish. I had not read the entire book but I do remember that there was a vicar.

He needed two statues(?) of great power to attain a power higher than God. He had already stolen one. The deuteragonist has a mission to get the stolen one back. At this point the protagonist and deuteragonist meet and the latter gets the former to help in the mission. It was then revealed that the deuteragonist was the second 'statue'. Repeated mentions had been made of 'the' King (later revealed to be God). Last I remember, there was a huge battle.

**UPDATE:**Just remembered, the deuteragonist was from Africa, so he was black. Plus, he and the protagonist could do magic by calling upon the power of that God.

Anyone familiar with the book?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?